# Are There Exercises To Build Software Development Research Skills?

Tags: active-learning

Would anyone refer me to exercises or resources to help learners build their research skills?  I mean I'm trying to get learners to think in terms of solving their own problems before bothering other, more senior, developers. Part of solving their own problems is knowing how to google for potential solutions--how to research.

Does anyone know of exercises I might use as learning activities to reinforce this skill?

### EDIT:

This is for a work training situation.

Comment: I just added the detail to the question.

Comment: you might want to change the title to indicate you are talking about researching software development questions, not general research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/) contains advanced google options to refine searches, you could make them into exercises for a work training simulation using Jupyter Notebooks such as "Search for stackoverflow intext: ag-grid AND module.ts", or exercises to walk git branches to become more familiar with the project.

You could also teach them to create a personal database of questions they've already asked, and how to search it, just so they aren't asking senior developers the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

One recommendation is to get them to answer a few StackOverflow questions of which they have zero knowledge of.

Another recommendation is to get them to use the ACM Digital Library (or some other database) to search for materials.

Both are good ways to learn to search using keywords and what to search for next when they've hit a dead-end.